# How to add disabled property to a bootstrap button dynamically without using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I have this button in bootstrap-vuejs

```
<b-button id="myBtn" variant="primary" @click="getLevel(searchData)" >Add</b-button>
```

I want to add disabled property dynamically based on a condition, how do i do it without jquery. I am not using jquery in my project.

```
<b-button id="myBtn" variant="primary" @click="getLevel(searchData)" diabled>Add</b-button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, we can do it with the help of `:disabled`

```
<b-button
          id="myBtn"
          variant="primary"
          @click="getLevel(searchData)"
          :disabled="enableButton"
        >Add</b-button>
```

Comment: @TroyMorehouse, I can not accept my own answer within 2 days.